# SQL Server import and export wizard - change concurrent setting

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to export several (~40) tables using the SQL Server import and export wizard (Right click database -> Task -> Export Wizard).

The wizard allows me to export all tables from database, 1 by 1, without error.

However, when I want to export all tables together, there is an error. I guess it is due to a concurrency issue (because the screen shows 2 tables are exporting together).

Can I change concurrency settings of the wizard? (set maxconcurrentexecutables to 1 in SQL Server). Or, do I need to use SSIS?

The error message is below:

> - Pre-execute (Error) Messages Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 2: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>     code: 0x80040E37.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc02020e8: Data Flow Task 2: Opening a rowset for "Table16" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.  (SQL Server
>     Import and Export Wizard)
> - Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 2: Destination 7 - Table16 failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.  (SQL Server
>     Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: What was the error

Comment: the export failed and stopped

Comment: please see error message added above

Comment: Whats wrong with backup restore? or do it in a SP. You can also use ssis. For me your errors is in ssis. You need a Dataflow task for each table.

Comment: The export operations stopped after the above error.
I think it should do it in a SP, instead of using the wizard then.